# How to disable disk unmount/mount sound

Tags: usb, sound, laptop

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a MacBook Pro, and hear the 'knock-knock' sound of a disk unmounting, then immediately mounting again periodically, when no physical devices are being changed. I have already turned system sound effects off in the settings menu, but that does not appear to affect the disk mount sound. How do I disable this sound effect?

Edit: I checked syslog and found a usb disconnect/connect event when the sound happened

```
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard kernel: [36412.160010] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 29
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard kernel: [36412.160167] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard upowerd[1172]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard upowerd[1172]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard kernel: [36412.532184] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard kernel: [36412.554871] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=8406, bcdDevice= 8.20
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard kernel: [36412.554875] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard kernel: [36412.554877] usb 2-4: Product: Card Reader
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard kernel: [36412.554879] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Apple
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard kernel: [36412.554880] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 000000000820
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard kernel: [36412.558095] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard kernel: [36412.558385] scsi host1: usb-storage 2-4:1.0
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 30: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4"
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 30 was not an MTP device
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard upowerd[1172]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0
May 26 19:03:48 Midgard upowerd[1172]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4
May 26 19:03:49 Midgard kernel: [36413.574344] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     APPLE    SD Card Reader   3.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
May 26 19:03:49 Midgard kernel: [36413.574881] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
May 26 19:03:49 Midgard kernel: [36413.576264] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Thoughts on stopping this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Open system settings> sound> here you can opt to turn ON and OFF related to specific applications/ tasks.

Comment: How does this relate to a HDD mounting and unmounting?

Comment: It is the only thing that can change sound effect when mounting and mounting disks. If it is not that sound and is related to HDD than it may be inherent energy saving feature. I had learned that in Mac Laptop HDD make click-click sound because it shut down HDD intermittently.

Comment: Sorry, that is my bad, I miss read the question, I thought the OP was talking about the physical click a disk makes as it spins up and down. They do say sound effect specifically.